# Remove box-shadow on upper side of mat-elevation

Tags: angular, angular-material

I added a `mat-paginator` on bottom of a `mat-table` which has a `mat-elevation-z4` class.

So I added a `mat-elevation-z4` class on the `mat-paginator` component too, but the paginator's upper shadow overflows on the table.
How can I remove only the upper shadow?

The `mat-elevation-z4` class is the following:

```
.mat-elevation-z4 {
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 
        0 4px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 
        0 1px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that the upper shadow is the third shadow, so I just had to remove it:

```
.mat-elevation-z4 {
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 
        0 4px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14);
}
```